# Is hash table with a perfect hash function better than an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, hashtable

I am working on a project that interprets election data, using custom data structures. Currently I am deciding on what datastructure is best for storing information about the final amount of votes the candidates achieved in different territorial units.

Since this is a homework, datastructures built in the language and datastructures from external libraries  are forbidden. Also, complexity for search must be lesser than O(n).

The hash function I intend to use looks like this

The key type would be of type unsigned int, the key itself would be the candidate's number on the ballot.

```cpp
template<typename K, typename T>
inline int CandidateResultsHashTable<K, T>::hashFunction(const K & key) const
    {
        return key % (amount_of_candidates + 1);
    }
```

The amount of candidates is known, although it can change between election rounds. All the data stored inside the hash table would be read from a file, which contains data for all candidates. So there shouldn't be any number that doesn't belong to a candidate.

I want to know, which implementation would be better based on access times and memory usage.

Comment: If they `key` is the number they are on the ballot why not just use an array with `amount_of_candidates` size and index directly to them using `key`?

Comment: That's the problem, I'm not sure, if there is anything, that hash table does better in this situation, since the candidate order seems to be the best key.

Comment: As far as I can tell you gain nothing.  It cost you cycles to compute the hash for the hash table.  As long as the keys are dense then just using a table with the key as the index is as fast as you can get.

Comment: If keys are just consecutive numbers then array like the proposed by @NathanOliver will be much more effective and easier to implement. Actually, it would still be good if keys aren't consecutive but they have some reasonable limit so the array is not too big. Only when there is no such limit you need some more sophisticated data structure.

Comment: since apparently keys are constitutive numbers just use array. You will not gain anything using hash here. Hash are good if you have larger amount of irregular keys or complex key compare method. Here it will be an overkill.

Comment: Hash table is rather tricky to implement. You need good enough hash function and also you need to deal with the situation when a few keys have the same hash. It's doable but I would suggest an array/list of key-value pairs or some sort of tree for better speed. (Although, you have to think about speed only if you deal with significant amount of data.)

Comment: `Since this is a homework, datastructures built in the language are forbidden` This is so dumb, why do they always do this.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox So you can concentrate on reinventing the wheel instead of designing some nice solution ;)

Comment: Well, there is about 10Mb of data files (for both election rounds), but the search complexity should be less than O(n) and sort complexity should be less then O(n^2).

Comment: So basically you are forbidden from using bubble sort and from linearly searching over list of key-value pairs. Everything else will pass. I would suggest a binary tree which directly maps to binary representation of the key. (0 - left branch, 1 right branch) EDIT: of course use the tree only in the situation when you cannot just do this in array.

Comment: @NO_NAME thanks for the clarification, I guess going with the array solution would be best in this situation.

Comment: @NO_NAME: the external key is already a number. So in that case the hash function is trivial and is the identity function (which as said in question is already a perfect hash). Simply it means directly using an array...

Comment: @SergeBallesta You're right, the array solution is a special case of hash table. I didn't think about that.

Comment: @NO_NAME could you please post your comments as an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've aggregated my comments into one answer.

This is a summary of different methods to implement a data structure called map (dictionary in some other languages).

---

### List of key-value pairs

The simplest way of solving your problem would be to an array/list of key-value pairs which you just check one by one until you find the right key.
It has very poor efficiency, though. O(n) is good only for small data sets. Speed doesn't matter that much and in case of very low amounts of data, this approach may be even faster due to the overhead that more sophisticated data structures have (e.g. calculating hash function).

This approach can be optimized quite significantly if you sort your keys and use binary search which is only O(log(n)).

---

### Hash table

Hash table is rather tricky to implement. You need good enough hash function.
Good hash function means that it has low amount of collisions - situations when two different keys have the same hash. You need program for this situation anyway but too high number of collisions decrease benefits from using hash table.

Your implementation is quite simple.

`key % (amount_of_candidates + 1)`

It is hard to tell if it is good enough without knowing how keys are assigned.

If keys are just consecutive numbers is perfectly good. (You don't even need `+ 1`.) Actually, in that situation you have a special case for hash table where you don't need to check for collisions because you can tell there won't be any.
At this point you can stop pretending that you use hash table and just make an array ;) Position of each candidate is just `key - smallest_key`. In fact, this would be a very effective solution: O(1).

You cannot simplify it that much if keys are assigned randomly. In this case your solution is mostly good. However, `(amount_of_candidates + 1)` is too small size for the hash table. It should be about 30% bigger than the amount of data ([load factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Load_factor)). This will decrease number of collisions to a reasonable level.

---

### Binary tree

Yet another solution would be to use a binary tree which directly maps to binary representation of the key. (0 - left branch, 1 right branch)
This is a method very similar to binary search in array but it allows to easily add new elements without resizing the array and sorting the new element into it.
The disadvantage of that solution would be higher memory requirements.

You could also experiment with other types of binary trees. You just need to remember to keep them balanced so they stay efficient. I don't really know much about balancing so I won't write more in this topic.

---

### Conclusion

I infer that, in you case, keys are just consecutive integers so I would recommend the solution which uses a plain array with indices tier directly to values of keys.
This is a very simple and at the same time very effective solution.

---

## Edit

OK, let's actually answer the question from the title.

The implementation of perfect hash function you showed is no different than an array. It is just another way of coding the same thing and depending on some factors the result assembly may be the same.

In the case of other hash function where keys are distributed over the whole range of `K`, straight array would be impractical / impossible to use due to huge amount of memory it would need. If you would succeed in allocating this amount of memory, array would be slightly faster because it wouldn't require to calculate hashes but it certainly wouldn't be worth it.